# octomap simple_example.cpp compilation error

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After success in building 3d maps i am trying to play with them for example: to detect tables in the 3d map. So trying to run the sample program. In the documentation it is said simple.cpp is an example but i could not find it neither in ros-octomap nor standalone octomap. But i found simple_example.cpp in standalone octomap folder which seems to be the updated file of simple.cpp.

But i am unable to compile it. Am i missing something ??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66607/octomap-simple_example.cpp-compilation-error/) by [kk](https://answers.ros.org/users/5289/kk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 225 on 2013-07-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please use the OctoMap mailing list for support that is not related to ROS: http://groups.google.com/group/octomap If you think you found a bug, just submit an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/OctoMap/octomap

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2013-07-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0